# How to have key-value pairs rather than array elements in a ListActivity?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list of items and their corresponding prices. I want to show these items(along with their prices on the right hand side) in a ListActivity. How can we do this? I have just used simple arrays that i pass on to the adapter till now. I would prefer an indexed datastructue to pass on to the adapter as I also need to sort the prices and then show them in the ListView.

Comment: So you'll have to create your own adapter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to customize your list rather than using the default list provided by Android. If you need any help, just contact me.